# String taken from database table post_meta is showing HTML tags on Frontend

Tags: post-meta

I have saved a string in post_meta table in wordpress database with html entities like-

`<p>Hello <b>Shashank</b>, I have an idea.</p>`

When I get this string on frontend using function

`get_post_meta(get_the_id(),field_name, true)`.

It echoes string with HTML entities as same as it stores in DB.

But I want to show this sting as "Hello **Shashank**, I have an idea."

How can I do this.?

Comment: what is the code that you use to output the value?

Answer (score 2):

Use the htmlspecialchars() function in PHP in the templates, because the wordpress-api does htmlspecialchars on import.

The following code works fine

```
<?php print htmlspecialchars_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked!

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you would need to decode encoded saved entities before echo them out using [`wp_kses_decode_entities`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_decode_entities) like this

```
$field = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),field_name, true)
echo wp_kses_decode_entities($field);
```